# How to write my onclick function in javaScript and bind it to an innerHTML

Tags: javascript

```
     var x = 10
     var y = 15
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = '<div 
     onclick=\'test("'x + '","' + y + '") > text  </div>';
```

Hello, I am new here, sorry for bad explain, but how what is the syntax in a function between js and html when i want to give parameters to the function?
I should get this `function : onclick='test(x,y)'`

Comment: Welcome! I can see you also new in HTML ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to set the `innerHTML` of your `#text` element to the result of test(x,y)
The traditional way of doing this would be something like

```
const answer = test(x,y)
document.getElementById('idOfThingToBeChanged').innerHTML = answer;
```

If you're trying to do this when a button is clicked on your page, you'd want to include this code as the content to your event listener, i.e.

```
document.getElementById('idOfThingToBeClicked')
   .addEventListener('click' => {
      (the code from above)
   });
```

If X and Y are values that are getting pulled from your HTML page, you'd want to grab them something like

```
const x = document.getElementById('idOfElement1').value;
const y = document.getElementById('idOfElement2').value;
const answer = test(x,y);
```

So that your final product looks something like

```
document.getElementById('elementToBeClicked')
   .addEventListener('click', () => {
      const x = document.getElementById('idOfElement1').value;
      const y = document.getElementById('idOfElement2').value;
      document.getElementById('elementToBeChanged')
         .innerHTML = test(x, y);
});
//This assumes you're injecting this code at a point after the page has loaded
```

Hope this covers all the bases but let me know if I can do better

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(x,y){
alert(x, y);
}

var x = 10
     var y = 15
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = `<div onclick="test(${x},${y})"> text</div>`;
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

PS: function test will show an alert in order to show you that it works